# MVVM Navigation between projects

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation

Let's say I have two MVVM projects, in the same solution. At one point in time I need to open MainWindow.xaml of Project 2, from my Project 1. And to make it simple let's say it just needs to happen on a click of a button - not in the code-behind, but rather in the view-model. Any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: If you want to just open project 2's mainwindow with project 1 still capable of referencing project 2's objects, then you probably need code-behind, after all. If you want to simply open project 2 and let it run on its own, just make a command which has `execute()` set to use `Process.Start()`

Comment: I don't quite understand the 'execute' and 'process.start' part... Could you explain

Comment: [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) allows you to start another program. `Execute()` refers to the method that you need to implement when you subclass from [ICommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform View navigation using MVVM? Win RT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134592/how-to-perform-view-navigation-using-mvvm-win-rt)

Comment: @AleksaKojadinovic also as far as the duplicate answer goes, I believe option two, using behaviors, is the better choice.